# Git Pull from Batch file with different user

Tags: c#, asp.net, git, batch-file

I have a user, let's call it "MyUser". It has a password, suppose it is "Password". This user has an SSH key for git. I try to run from my ASP.NET application a batch file which issues git commands, it is at a location which is passed as a parameter. My function is as follows:

```
    private void ExecuteCommand(string path, int timeout)
    {
        Process process = new Process();

        process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + path + "\"";
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        //processInfo.WorkingDirectory = Config.GitHubRepoPath;
        process.StartInfo.UserName = "MyUser";
        process.StartInfo.Password = new System.Security.SecureString();
        process.StartInfo.Password.AppendChar('P');
        process.StartInfo.Password.AppendChar('a');
        process.StartInfo.Password.AppendChar('s');
        process.StartInfo.Password.AppendChar('s');
        process.StartInfo.Password.AppendChar('w');
        process.StartInfo.Password.AppendChar('o');
        process.StartInfo.Password.AppendChar('r');
        process.StartInfo.Password.AppendChar('d');
        // *** Redirect the output ***
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        process.Start();

        // *** Read the streams ***
        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

        if (timeout <= 0)
        {
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
        else
        {
            process.WaitForExit(timeout);
        }


        int exitCode = process.ExitCode;
        process.Close();
        return new ShellCommandReturn { Error = error, ExitCode = exitCode, Output = output };
    }
```

But when I run this function, the ExitCode is -1073741502 and error and output are empty. How can I fix this behavior?

Please help me, I have tried to solve this literally for days.

Comment: Can you execute any batch file successfully with this code?

Comment: Yes, unless they contain git pull.

Comment: If it were me, I would next verify that the account the batch files run under has the appropriate permissions. (But that's just me.)

Comment: Yes, it has godlike permissions to the given project, but thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think redirecting both standard error and standard output & attempts to consume both synchronously is wrong. Please see this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Allow me to copy excerpt:

*A deadlock condition results if the parent process calls p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd followed by p.StandardError.ReadToEnd and the child process writes enough text to fill its error stream. The parent process would wait indefinitely for the child process to close its StandardOutput stream. The child process would wait indefinitely for the parent to read from the full StandardError stream.*

The other thing is ... when you invoke a cmd.exe instance, try adding a "/c" argument too.